# C# Stream Program Output to an Audio Input Device

Tags: audio, naudio, wasapi

I have a program that generates a PCM Audio stream (as a MemoryStream). I want to send this to an audio input (recording) device in windows so that an application that is set to get input from that recording device will get the output generated by my program as input.

Any simple way to tackle this? If it is going to help, I can generate Waveform output stream from my program.

As an additional complication, any solution that depends on looping back the audio output to input wont work because I have another application that is already doing that to capture the default output.